# How do I cycle through file locations on counsel results?

Tags: counsel, swiper

I'm trying to look for all the occurrences of a word in my project and I'm using counsel for this. I get the list of occurrences and their locations in the minibuffer, but I'd like to cycle through the files at exactly the location of the occurrences. This works perfectly with swiper, by just doing `C-n/C-p`, but is there a way to get counsel to do this?

(I'm using counsel-rg if that matters)